# C# udpclient/udp socket -- working locally but not on global addresses

Tags: c#, udp

I have a very annoying problem. I have a mIRC/Skype application, meaning chatroom with text and voice. The text & chatroom stuff goes through TCP and works flawlessly, while the UDP only relays recorded data to other connected clients.

Between two clients on my home network, audio transfer works fine. But against a global client, the server will niether receive packets from him, or he will receive packets from the server.

Here's an example:

Server is using udp socket while client is using udpclient, but the result is the same anyway and it works locally too..

server global ip: 222.222.222.222
server local ip: 192.168.2.3
server port: 9999

client global ip: 111.111.111.111
client local ip: 192.168.0.100
client port: 8888

The server 
*binds its socket to 192.168.2.3 : 9999
*receives from 111.111.111.111 : 8888
*sends to 111.111.111.111.111 : 8888

the client
*binds its socket to 192.168.0.100
*receives from 222.222.222.222 : 9999
*sends to 222.222.222.222 : 9999

...you get what I mean. I have no idea why the data dosn't get through. I've tried sending/receiving on port 53 (for both client and server) and that shouldn't even be necessary right? I mean traffic should go through anyway (just like it does with games like call of duty) and no there is no windows firewall active, only router in that case.

the client/server uses connect() each other, not receiveFrom/sendTo. I tried using that too but no difference.

I get no exceptions or anything either so its impossible to debug :(

What could possibly be the reason? Consider the fact it works locally but not globally; I do agree it really sounds like a firewall issue, but as I'e described above I dont see how thats applicable in my scenario, and I tried on port 53 and other open ports..

Cheers :)

EDIT: its quite alot of code, but if necessary I can copy it in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't broadcast UDP to the entire internet (I assume this is what you mean by 'global') - it will only work within the subnet of the machine issuing the broadcast.  This is why it works locally but not with the remote machines.

You might want to consider using IP Multicast instead:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Multicast

That said you may also have problems with that as some routers (that you have no control over) will not allow the multicast packets to be forwarded.

Comment: The reason you are not seeing an exception is that UDP is fire and forget.  The issuer is sending out the broadcast as it does in your local setup without issue, problem is that the receiver is not able to pick up the broadcast.

Comment: By globally, I mean to a client over the internet, instead of just over the local network :p for example over the local net I just use the local IP to connect instead of the global IP. (Global maybe was a bad word for it) Multicast is simply sending to several computers by duplicating the packets at the necessary gateways right? I simply want to try first get a 1-to-1 connection working

Comment: If it is just a 1 to 1 connection you need try using standard sockets/remoting/wcf instead of using a broadcast protocol.

Comment: I am using UDP sockets to send/receive if thats what you meant.